# SQL Latest Date by circuit ID

Tags: sql

I would like help with this sql.  I need to find the latest date for each circuit ID (field name-strip_ec_circuit_id) based on a created date(field name-create_bill_date). I need to only find the latest date, while the other ones can be deleted.  Can you help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic group by query that should work in any database:

```
select strip_ec_circuit_id, max(create_bill_date) as lastDate
from t
group by strip_ec_circuit_id
```

I'm not sure what you mean by delete all the others.  Do you actually want to delete the rows from the table that are not the max?